# Apache PHP script to Start Tomcat Server in Linux

Tags: php, tomcat, administration

I made a php script to start Tomcat Server (catalina.sh start) thats works well from command line in Linux. It was run as ROOT with a different set of ENV.

However, I would like to do the same from the Web, Please note due to security issues, this script would only be accesible via localhost (for administration only), so we ironed out the security issue.

Problem is, Tomcat is not starting (we could confirm that from the logs, nothing was initiated). We coded lots of Echo around catalina.sh and its providing the right echo output.

Im sure theres an easier way to do this. Any Ideas?

The PHP script does the following:

1. Changes Dir to th Tomcat Bin
2. Starts Catalina.sh Script vis startup.sh

OUTPUT FROM COMMAND LINE PRINT ENV:

```
ORBIT_SOCKETDIR=/tmp/orbit-root
HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm
HISTSIZE=1000
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=c111d8f81ff89709b78252c50000000d-1338310776.433586-1797694621
GTK_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk/gtkrc:/root/.gtkrc-1.2-gnome2
WINDOWID=73400323
QTDIR=/usr/lib/qt-3.3
QTINC=/usr/lib/qt-3.3/include
USER=root
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-bsFAQz/socket.ssh
GNOME_KEYRING_SOCKET=/tmp/keyring-bsFAQz/socket
USERNAME=root
SESSION_MANAGER=local/unix:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1788,unix/unix:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1788
PATH=/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/root/bin
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/root
DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome
PWD=/programs/tomcat/bin
GDM_KEYBOARD_LAYOUT=us
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=1779
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
GDM_LANG=en_US.UTF-8
GDMSESSION=gnome
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
SHLVL=3
HOME=/root
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
LOGNAME=root
QTLIB=/usr/lib/qt-3.3/lib
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-9HtQtRhCr9,guid=e1755bf07ea8a916f0a4e3f70000001c
LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
WINDOWPATH=1
DISPLAY=:0.0
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
XAUTHORITY=/var/run/gdm/auth-for-root-IT2DiY/database
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

OUTPUT FROM APACHE PRINT ENV:

```
TERM=xterm
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
PWD=/programs/tomcat/bin
LANG=C
SHLVL=4
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

Comment: .. really need to see the script.. output.. etc

Comment: The output is identical actually. I added the PRINTENV for both situations. I will try again to run JAVA command & port the output.

Answer (score 0):

try using [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

```
exec('full path to your script')
```

Comment: Hi, I found that the problem is actually permissions to run /usr/bin/java from Apache (user apache) as a PHP script, hence any form of exec will not work. Im looking for a workaround.